# Why are quotes necessary for files argument when calling this Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm quite new to Bash scripting.  I have a "testscript", which I used as the basis for a more advanced / useful script:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$1
for a in $files
do
    echo "$a"
done
```

When I call this without any quotes it just picks up one file in a directory:

```
testscript *.txt
```

But when I call it with quotes it works correctly and picks out all the text files:

```
testscript '*.txt'
```

What is going on here?

Comment: To be very, **very** clear, the right way to fix this is to run `for a in "$@"; do` (or `for a; do`) in your script, thus leaving the globbing to the outer shell, not to leave out the quotes.

Comment: Also see: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Comment: This well worth a look.  http://guide.bash.academy/

Comment: See also [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/80216)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you call a program

```
testscript *.txt
```

then your *shell* does the expansion and works out all the values.  So it might, effectively call your program as

```
testscript file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

Now your program only looks at `$1` and so only works on `file1.txt`.

By quoting on the command line you are passing the literal string `*.txt` to the script, and that is what is stored in `$1`.  Your `for` loop then expands it.

Normally you would use `"$@"` and not `$1` in scripts like this.

This is a "gotcha" for people coming from CMD scripting, where the command shell doesn't do *globbing* (as it's known) and always passes the literal string.

Comment: Just to clarify (for people other than the author of the above answer), using `"$@"` (as opposed to `$@` or `$1` `$2` `$3`) will cause each filename to be quoted `"file1.txt"` `"file2.txt"` etc.  For `file1.txt` this is meaningless, but if you have `my file.txt`, the quoting is *critical* to prevent the shell parsing to turn it into two filenames, one named `my` and one named `file.txt`.  Always quote user input and glob expansion lest you be very unhappy some day.

Comment: And this isn't just a theoretical - Mac OS X once shipped with an update script that didn't properly quote arguments and ended up deleting peoples' hard drives in some circumstances.

Comment: @fluffy, do you have a link about that?

Comment: @Wildcard Unfortunately I'm unable to find any articles about it, but it was big news in the tech world when it happened. I want to say it was in 2003/2004 or thereabouts, back when Apple was still getting the hang of being a UNIX distributor.

Comment: @wildcard Ah, found it! http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/OSX/itunes2_erased_drives.html - it was actually an iTunes upgrade script that was the culprit.

Comment: @fluffy something similar happened to Steam a few months ago, although I'm not sure it was related to globbing in particular.

Answer (score 7):

Without quotes the shell expands `*.txt` before invoking the script, so `$1` is only the first file that gets expanded.  All of the `txt` files are arguments to your script at that point (assuming there aren't too many).

With quotes that string is passed without being expanded into the script, which then lets the `for` do the expansion, as you're hoping for.